# Using Excel data with Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, require, sheetjs

I'm trying to extract data from an Excel file for use in JS.

I'm a novice coder so bear that in mind please.

I'm currently trying to use the SheetJS API and the nodeJS module (I don't really understand how these interact but I've just been following Youtube videos, mainly).

I've got to a point where my JS file has a require(xlsx) function, which then allows me to read the xlsx file.

The first problem I've come across is that this then means that normal JS code won't work in the browser - I've investigated and it seems like this is because the require function is part of nodeJS and not JS itself, although why exactly this means that normal JS written below it won't work I can't really understand. Also, I can't find any actual solutions to this problem (ie written in plain, idiot-proof English).

Is there some very basic walkthrough guide to importing the data from Excel and then doing useful things with it (eg I was hoping to populate a table based on a selection of a drop-down menu (itself populated from Excel)).

Sorry, I'm a bit stuck generally.

Thanks

Comment: SheetJS will work in the browser, albeit the setup is different. Check out https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs#installation and https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/tree/master/demos/xhr The important point here is that the browser can't open files from your computer directly like a Node.js server can. You will need to run a web server that serves the XLSX file so the browser can retrieve and parse it.

Comment: Thanks. I've dragged the xlsx file into the repository, surely the browser can access it from there like it would an image or a css file?